# Combobox in winform and many entries

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, addrange

I'm trying to get a combobox in winform that has around 5'000 entries. I've run into a problem before - addrange hangs with this many entries. I created a seperate control to do this for myself without lagging, but I'm adding this functionality to existing comboboxes.

I was looking up VirtualizingStackPanel for WPF when trying to see if I could get around this.

Is there a way to improve the performance of addrange for a couple of thousand string entries?

Comment: Are you sure that a combobox is the right interface element to represent 5000 entries? I think this is not ideal for the user.

Comment: It is in this case : The program has been running this way since the start and they're very used to it.         I am curious what others would use instead of a combobox? Listbox, etc.

Comment: As a user I would prefer a textbox with some kind of autocomplete..

Comment: Or better yet: a textbox with a button that opens a new resizable window that has all the items in, with find-as-you-type substring item elimination.

Comment: I need to demand my job give me a better computer to program in then a 5 year old half broken laptop so I don't miss that my code is running inside a for loop.           On a side note, dear god did I improve the effeciency of that program since I thought that wasn't the bottleneck >.<

Comment: One of my computers is 8 years old and works perfectly fine for coding on (Athlon64 3200, 4GB RAM, GeForce 6800GT). I don't buy your excuses :)

Comment: You also don't have autocad, a few image and video manipulation hardwares, VS and a few other things running in tandem >.>   I'm a total resource hog ^.^;;;; It was also a lapse on my behalf, I just got use to R#'s ending tags and they've stopped working recently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using `ComboBox.BeginUpdate` and `ComboxBox.EndUpdate`? Using those methods improves performance when adding items.

Of course, if you have 5000 items then maybe using a ComboBox isn't the right control (having more than 200 items or so makes scrolling impossible, which defeats the point of having a drop-down selector). Have you considered using a normal textbox but with an autocomplete provider instead?

Comment: +1 for the second paragraph. As for the first, don't expect any gains from `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` if you are already using `AddRange`.

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph. BeginUpdate and EndUpdate helped me a lot with performance problems I have had with adding a lot of controls to forms.